How does python know on which memory location what variable is stored?
When i try to assign a variable having a value to another variable, it reference the same value/memory location the value is stored
Python code:-
a = 10

b = a

Now if we print hex(id(a)) and same for b it will return the same memory location for both the variables. How python knows that there is a value at some memory location?
Does python have mapping table or something? or it iterates all the locations used in a specific program/script ?

Yes, Python manages symbols (variable names) and what they refer to under the hood. It’s fairly pointless to think about it in terms of memory locations, as Python is too high level for that and that’s all abstracted away from you. That ids are internally based on memory locations should be of no consequence to you.

So, the semantics of Python are different from the semantics of a language like C. In C, a variable is a named location in memory. In C, a = b means something like "copy he data located at memory location 'b' into memory location 'a'", but in Python, a = b means something like "the label 'a' now refers to the same object that the label 'b' is referring to right now". You can think of them like name tags on people.

In the CPython implementation, variables store a pointer to whatever object they refer to. The CPython implementation knows there's an object at the location a variable is pointing to because the variable is pointing to that location.
a = b doesn't need to look up 10 in some global registry, or iterate over every single memory location the program has used. The implementation knows what address to use because the a variable recorded that address.
In general, Python knows about the existence of objects that references refer to because those references exist. If there were an object somewhere with no references to it (which can only happen with buggy or deliberately broken C-level code), Python would have no idea the object existed.

In Python there is an important difference between variables, which are names, and objects, which are data items that occupy memory space (storage). In your script there are two variables, named 'a' and 'b', but there is only one object, the number 10.
Your first line of code creates an object, 10, and "binds" the variable 'a' to that object.
Your second line of code doesn't create any new objects.  It binds the variable 'b' to the same object as variable 'a'.
The id(x) method returns an item of information about the object bound to the name 'x'.  Its meaning is implementation-dependent, and my understanding is that typically it is indeed the memory address.  But that isn't something you should count on.  What you can count on, so far as I know, is that each object has a unique id().  But there is no limit to the number of variables that can be bound to each object.
If, and only if, two variables a and b refer to the same object, id(a) == id(b).  That's about all you should use id() for, although sometimes that piece of information can be valuable for debugging.
If you added a third line to your script, like this:
a = 11

the name 'a' will now be bound to a new object, 11.  The variable 'b' will not be affected and will continue to be bound to the object 10.  Then id(a) will be different from id(b).
